# Multiple radio buttons, only 1 can be selected - Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5

I have a little app, where in the navigation bar I want some options for filtering and ordering of data. My idea was to use radio buttons to select from the options, from example, ordering asc or desc:

```html
<li class="nav-item active">
    <input type="radio" {checked]='ascOrDesc'
                        (change)='ascOrDesc = !ascOrDesc' /> Asc.
</li>
<li class="nav-item active">
    <input type="radio" [checked]='!ascOrDesc'
                        (change)='ascOrDesc = !ascOrDesc' /> Desc.
</li>
```

With this, when they select something, it unselects the other radio button, and I can know in my component, based on `ascOrDesc`, what is selected.

Now, I need to have something that filters between 4 different options, but I can't make it to work like the example before. What I tried is:

```html
<div style="padding-right: 0.5rem;">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <input type="radio" [checked]='esmeralda' (change)='esmeraldaChange()' /> Esmeralda
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <input type="radio" [checked]='ttesub6'  /> Tte Sub 6
    </li>
</div>
<div>
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <input type="radio" [checked]='pilarReno'  /> Pilar Reno
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <input type="radio" [checked]='todo'  /> Todo
    </li>
```

And the idea is that when something changes (in this case only $esmeralda$), it calls a function, and it changes the values of the other vars (ttesuu6, pilarReno, and todo) and set them to false, so that they uncheck, like:

```js
esmeraldaChange() {
  if (this.esmeralda) {
    this.ttesub6 = false;
    ...
  }
}
```

But, this is not triggering the change on the other radio buttons. Why?

Comment: you have to tell the radio buttons that they are for the same option set

Comment: The radio buttons should have the same `name`, and each radio button should have its own `[value]`. You can then use `[(ngModel)]` and bind a variable to the radio buttons (the same variable for all of them).